# Como obter dados de processamento e memória do sistema Windows em Java?

Tags: java, windows

Como faço para em código Java mostrar uso de processamento e memória do Windows?

Comment: Bem vindo a Sopt. Creio que sua pergunta esteja ampla demais. Poderia editar e fornecer mais detalhes do que você quer fazer com essas informações?

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que essa classe pode te ajudar a pegar todos os dados que você quer.

```java
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
operatingSystemMXBean.getSystemCpuLoad();
```

De uma olhada na documentação completa [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, era o que eu estava procurando

Comment: Não deixa de apertar no check abaixo do up vote caso tenha resolvido sua pergunta. É onde vc marca como resposta.